# Tunneling VNC over SSH

Tags: macos, ssh, vnc

I would like to run VNC over SSH (tunneling) on a Mac. 
I am behind a Firewall and I can't modify the Firewall other than open Port 22 or the VNC port. 
Is there any way I can run VNC over SSH, without the need to forward the VNC port over SSH.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can tunnel anything over SSH that only requires outbound connections on a static port number. For instance, it's very easy to tunnel an HTTP connection over SSH, because it only requires an outbound connection on a single port (usually 80). However, tunneling active FTP over SSH is more difficult because FTP uses an outbound control channel (port 21) for sending commands as well as an inbound data channel (on a dynamic port) for transmitting data. Passive FTP gets around this, however, by putting everything on the control channel.

Comment: Would you be able to use a zero config VPN like LogMeIn Hamachi? It creates outbound initial requests on both the source and destination computers therefore no pinholes required in the Firewall.